# Random audio button stops working after set amount of clicks

Tags: java, android

I'm having a bit of a problem, basically I've currently got a single button setup to play a variety of sounds, on each click a random sound should play. That works fine however after a certain amount of clicks of the button which equals the amount of sound files I have it playing, it stops playing anymore. Pretty stumped as to why it's happening and a way of getting around it.

```
private final int SOUND_CLIPS = 11;
private int mfile[] = new int[SOUND_CLIPS];
private Random rnd = new Random();
MediaPlayer mpButtonOne;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //I list all my sounds files here, removed for sake of saving space.        

    Button bButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(myMenu.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)]);
            mpButtonOne.seekTo(0);
            mpButtonOne.start();
            }
    });
    }
 }
```

All of this code does what I want it to do which is play a random sound clip out of a list of clips on every button click however it seems to only do it a set amount of times and then stops playing anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how many times does it stop after? and why are you calling `seekTo(0)` before you call start? Also, after it stops playing sounds does it make any messages in the logcat when you press the button?

Comment: It stops playing after about 11 clicks which is the amount of clips I have stored to play and no I'm getting no message in the logcat.

Comment: In the 11 clips that it does play, does it ever repeat a clip that has already been played? Or does it play all 11 different clips every time, just in a different order?

Comment: It repeats clips that have already been played so not only 11 once in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

Are you releasing the MediaPlayer anytime?  You seem to be creating a new one with every click an never releasing it.  Eventually you can run out of resources.

Read the section on Releasing MediaPlayer:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Essentially you want to implement an onCompletionListener and register it with your MediaPlayer, and do your clean up there:

```
mpButtonOne.setOnCompletionListener(new SoundCompletionListener());


    private class SoundCompletionListener implements OnCompletionListener{

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if(mp!=null){
            mp.release();
            mp=null;
        }   
    }
}
```